# C# change 2D arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got this 2D array :

```
mapData = new int[,]
{
    {2,0,2,2,2},
    {1,0,0,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,1},
    {1,2,2,2,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1},
};
```

However I want to change some of these numbers when certain events happen (this represents my tile map, so I want to replace some tiles).

How would I go about changing for example the two in the right corner?

I can do this :

```
mapData = new int[,]
{
    {2,0,2,2,3},
    {1,0,0,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,1},
    {1,2,2,2,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1},
};
```

But this seems really inefficient.

So how would a better way of doing this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the contents of a 2D array by doing

```
mapData[0, 4] = 3;
```

This should change the value in the upper right corner (or lower left -- I'm forgetting the order of the indices).

Comment: Thanks erik, I'm just started out with 2d arrays so sorry if it was a "noob" question

Comment: @Erik fyi it does "row, column", so it changes the upper right.